# Combinatorics Question - thank you!

Tags: combinatorics

In a dresser drawer, there's a jumble of 5 red socks, 5 blue socks, 7 green socks, and 4 yellow socks. What is the minimum number of socks we have to pick up in order to guarantee that at least 4 will be of the same color?

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It will be better if you show at least some of your work ... or what you have attempted ... that way people would be more likely to answer your questions

Comment: This question has been reposted from Brilliant.org. Note that user88755 also just posted 2 problems from Brilliant.org. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you have something like a link to the question on brilliant.org?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker [Here](https://brilliant.org/i/ZA4k9o/) you go. This is a question that I'm using in a diagnostic quiz, so you might see different values other than 5, 5, 7, but the rest of the phrasings are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If we are very unlucky, when we pick $12$ socks there will be $3$ of each colour.

Comment: Why unlucky? When you put four of the same color together they explode!

Comment: This question has been reposted from Brilliant.org. I'm requesting that you do not display any hints or solutions. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I'll just make things simple since I'm not sure how in-depth is your combinatorics ... anyway, let's assume the worse scenario, which is that the first few socks you picked up is in this order:

red, blue, green, yellow, red, blue, green, yellow, red, blue, green, yellow, ... what's next?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply as the other question was locked. Will delete afterwards. [Brilliant.org](brilliant.org) offers students weekly challenging problems in Mathematics and Science, for them to practice and improve their problem solving skills. We have also started hosting [competitions](https://brilliant.org/competitions/) with attractive prizes.

Comment: This question has been reposted from Brilliant.org. I'm requesting that you do not display any hints or solutions. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant Challenge Master

Answer (score 0):

The earlier hints show that $12$ socks are not enough.  We also need to prove that $13$ is a sufficient number of socks (regardless of how the socks are chosen).

Let $r,b,g,y$ be the number of red, blue, green and yellow socks chosen, respectively.  Since we choose $13$ socks, we know $r+b+g+y=13$.  We want to show $\max(r,b,g,y) \geq 4$.

Suppose $\max(r,b,g,y) < 4$.  It follows that $r \leq 3$, $b \leq 3$, $g \leq 3$ and $y \leq 3$.  Hence
\begin{align*}
r+b+g+y & \leq 3+3+3+3 \\
& = 12 \\
& < 13,
\end{align*}
giving a contradiction.